# ALSA snd_pcm_readi & snd_pcm_writei

Tags: linux, alsa

What is the difference between `snd_pcm_writei` and  `snd_pcm_readi` ? Both of these functions seems to be playing back from buffer when I tried using them ? Seems like only how handle is configured `SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE/SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK` determines the outcome. I was under the impression that write is for playing back and read for capturing.
Could someone clarify this and post a good tutorial for ALSA ?

```
    frames = snd_pcm_writei(handle, Buffer, Size);
    frames = snd_pcm_readi(handle, Buffer, Size);
```

Answer (score 2):

`snd_pcm_writei()` copies data from your own buffer into the device's buffer, and works only with playback devices.

`snd_pcm_readi()` copies data from the device's buffer into your own buffer, and works only with capture devices.